# I am having a problem implementing a custom command

Tags: drush

I am running Drupal 9 on DDEV.  I am following detailed docs I have found online for implementing a custom drush command, but having no luck.

Here is my drush.services.yml in the root of my custom module, sp_retrieve, and my class file, RetrieveContentCommands.php in src/Commands.

When I clear cache and try "drush list", my command is not listed.  When I try to run the command I get "There are no commands defined in the sp_retrieve namespace."

```
services:
  sp_retrieve.commands:
    class: \Drupal\sp_retrieve\Commands\RetrieveContentCommands
    arguments: ['@entity_type.manager', '@logger.factory', '@logger.dblog']
    tags:
      - { name: drush.command }
```

```
namespace Drupal\sp_retrieve\Commands;

use Drush\Commands\DrushCommands;

class RetrieveContentCommands extends DrushCommands {
   /**
   * A custom Drush command to archive a user.
   * 
   * @command sp_retrieve:archive_user
   * 
   * @aliases archive_user
   * 
   * @usage sp_retrieve:archive_user
   * 
   * @param string $userId
   * @param string $deactived
   * @param string $reason
   * 
   *
   */
   public static function archiveUser(string $userId, $deactived = FALSE, $reason = '') {  
      var_dump("foo");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your command methods must be instance members, not static. Remove the `static` keyword and you should be able to continue

```
public function archiveUser(string $userId, $deactived = FALSE, $reason = '')
```

You have also defined several arguments for the service, but not implemented the constructor to receive them - that will probably throw an error once the `static` keyword is removed and the service is picked up, so worth fixing now.

It's also worth bearing in mind that it's now recommended to [use PHP attributes rather than docblock annotations to define commands](https://mglaman.dev/blog/writing-drush-commands-php-attributes#:%7E:text=For%20Drush%2C%20this%20allows%20specifying,more%20without%20writing%20PHP%20code.&text=Our%20command%20and%20alias%20annotations,and%20wrapped%20in%20brackets%20%5B%5D%20.). This is available from Drush 12 onwards.